# Transfer or swap?

Tags: address.transfer, swaps

I'm newbie in crypto, and I think I made a "mistake"...
I mine a coin who haven't got any exchange or swap ! Is there a way to use smart contract to help me ? Like a function tranfer or swap ? But I don't know how to do, or if it's possible .
PS: sorry for my english :)
Thank you.
Edit: I'm talking about swap for a ERC20 token on the etheurem blockchain.

Comment: Which coin are you mining? How are you mining it? If there's no exchange that accepts that coin then it is like it never existed. Smart contract can't be used to exchange coins if there's no exchange that accept it.

Comment: Hi ! It's bitcoinX (BCX). There is some exchange but it's impossible to do a deposit. All the same.Thanks

Comment: Or use a wrapped token ? But how to give the value of my coin to the token ?